# really simple: file permissions

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I really don't understand.

I have on my localhost web projects on the path `/var/php/project_name`

I have changed ownership of that files to my user name via `chown`. Now, assume I have `private` directory inside project (so the path is `/var/php/project_name/private`)

and I type command:

```
chmod -R u=rwx,g=rx,o= private
```

so the permissions are:

```
drwxr-x---  4 maciej maciej 4096 2012-02-02 11:54 private
```

but when I try to `cd private` i get permissions denied. What the f... is going on?

Yes, I am logged as `maciej`: maciej@mkk:/var/php/edited_name/private$

OS: newest Ubuntu

UPDATE:

sorry guys - it was my typo.. i lied to you: i removed x permission but included it in the question :|

Comment: try bombing the permissions with a `chmod 777` and see if anything happens.

Comment: Read (r) has nothing to do with accessing a directory. It's the execute (x) bit that allows you to cd into a directory. What happened to you doesn't happen to me though....

Comment: @Migs your comment was answer - i lied to you all in the question, my bad.. please make this comment an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read (r) has nothing to do with accessing a directory. It's the execute (x) bit that allows you to cd into a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Only user `maciej` and group `maciej` are allowed to enter `private`. Are you logged in as `maciej`?

Comment: yes, I am: maciej@mkk:/var/php/edited_name/private$

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as you've written it:

```
/tmp/mkk $ mkdir private
/tmp/mkk $ chmod -R u=rwx,g=rx,o= private/
/tmp/mkk $ id
uid=1000(nick) gid=100(users) groups=...
/tmp/mkk $ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-x--- 2 nick users 4096 Feb 29 13:32 private
/tmp/mkk $ cd private/
/tmp/mkk/private $
```

Are you definitely logged in as the `maciej` user? Are you running SELinux or similar?

Comment: yes i am, that is why it is strange to me. maybe it is because I do not own parent folder - var? but this would be strange

Comment: Well, could you add the output of `ls -ld /var/php/project_name/{,private}` to the question just in case?